# Testcontainers: "Timed out waiting for container port to open" with GitLab CI

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, testcontainers

Have the following `DockerComposeContainer` starting as part of my integration tests:

```
DockerComposeContainer container = new DockerComposeContainer(new File("docker-compose.yml"))
        .withExposedService("es1", 9200, Wait.forListeningPort().withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300)));
```

This works locally, but when running this test as part of a maven command in a my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, which  per https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/gitlab_ci/ includes:

```
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
```

This causes the following error after waiting the 300 second timeout period:

> Timed out waiting for container port to open (dind ports: [9200, 32769, 9300] should be listening)

Haven't been able to find a solution to this online.

Edit:

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  es1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    hostname: es1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      - "dicovery.type=single-node"
    volumes:
      - ./tmpdata/es1/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Answer (score 0):

This was apparently just due to the lack of docker-compose installation on Gitlab runners.  I ended up using an `ElasticsearchContainer` instead of the `DockerComposeContainer`.